# Presheafs on sets of prime number constituents of natural numbers

Tags: sheaf-theory

This question is meant both to really try to understand presheaves and sections as well as check for feasibility for an idea that I have. Forgive if the question misses the point of presheaves; if my example lacks the generality.  I am wanting to both understand the concepts as well as see if my idea works.

Question: Is there a way to define a presheaf on prime number subsets of natural numbers and if so would the ideas below work?

Some work:   Perhaps a presheaf is similar to various numbers and there factors e.g. $14 \subset 70$ and $14 \subset 42$ as the set of its factors $\{2,7\} \subset \{2,5,7\}$ and $\{2,7\} \subset \{2,3,7\}$ so although there are other numbers that are both less then 70 and 42 such as 15, the set of numbers of the prime decomposition of 15 is not a subset of that of 70 or 42 so it can not evolve to either.

Now I am investigating a topology on finite sets of natural numbers such as $\{2,5,7\}$ and am thinking it would be something such as the $\textit{Discrete Topology}$ in which each set is both open and closed i.e. $\{5\} \subset \{2,5,7\}$ as well as all $2^n$ subsets. If the subset $\{2,5,7\}$ were open we could look at the category of open sets $Op_X$ on $X$, the objects are open sets  and the morphisms are inclusions. I am thinking that maybe Let $X = \bigcup U_i; U_i \in X$ a cover of $X$. If that were the case then:

A presheaf is a functor $F$ on $X$ which associates to each open set $U_i \subset X$, a set $F(U_i)$, and to an open set $U_h \subset U_i$
a map $\rho_{U_{i}U_{h}}: F(U_i) \rightarrow F(U_h)$

Now can I or should I be able to treat take say $F(70) \rightarrow F(14)$ as the reverse morphism which $F(70) \rightarrow \{2,5,7\}$ and $F(14) \rightarrow \{2,7\}$ where we would have the morphism $\{2,5,7\} \rightarrow \{2,7\}$ which would make the triangle commute (if it does)? I see that $5$ is lost and likewise $3$ is lost in the morphism from $G(42)$ where $G \in  Op_X^{op} \rightarrow Set$.

I read on another stackexchange answer that "A presheaf is a set that evolves continuously over a topological space $X$" so it seems that I am looking in to how the evolution of numbers works for base sets that are common to particular numbers. I am thinking that they would be like a "Stalk".

I know that in Category theory one is not concerned with individual elements, or from my understanding is not supposed to be. I am not sure how to go about understanding the inclusions and do understand that there could be many such inclusions e.g. there could be several possible subsets of $F(70)$ and whatever is going on would cover a set of elements that fit the criteria.  Picking one of those elements though (one of a possible several) I suppose that part of what I am stuck on is that I don't see what $F$ really does in this example, i.e. would $F(70) \rightarrow \{2,5,7\}$? I am associating the number 70 to a set and then doing mappings such as $F(70) \rightarrow F(14)$ which would then just project on to a subset. What does this do for me, why is it useful?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: "Is there a way to define a presheaf of natural numbers?" On any topological space there are a lots of presheaves. You have to specifiy your question in order to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I also don't see any justification of the tags "algebraic topology", "set theory", "algebraic number theory" here.

Comment: I removed the algebraic topology and put general topology in instead. As far as algebraic number theory, I think that the sets of prime numbers and their relation to presheaves is dependent on the uniqueness of prime factorization and am curious to know how that works together with sets (i.e. set theory) so as to understand filtering and such as well as inclusions and the uniqueness thereof (reminds me of prime ideals - another reason for number theory).

Comment: I am confused as to why anyone would want to close this question - I am trying quite hard to find simplistic working examples of pre-sheaves and believe that others also and think that this question would help both myself and others gain intuition concerning natural numbers and concepts of ideas such as filters.

Comment: You ignore the prime numbers when you use the discrete topology ... because this means that you actually start with any countably infinite set, without using any additional structure. I have voted to close since the question is unclear + too broad + not focused. Any answer will just result in babbling about the definition and examples of presheaves.

Comment: @Martin, ok, I severely reduced the question - it did have a lot of information in it and led to other questions.  One at a time I suppose, if I have troubles with working out how "sections" would apply to the above, then I can post another question.  I want to see if my idea is a valid one for a pre-sheaf in the first place; could work from there.  Also, thanks for the heads up on the prime number and countably infinite set.  Indeed, I will need to put some additional structure on it once I figure out if it my example would even work.

Comment: I've removed some irrelevant tags. Mentioning sets does not make a question related to set theory. Similarly with the other two tags I removed.

Comment: Ok, that makes two of you mentioning the tag thing; I respect your credentials on the matter.

Comment: @Relative0 the way your formulated your question above is very vague. Frankly, I don't quite understand what precisely it is you are trying to do. It sounds as if you have some idea and you want to relate it to presheaves. But is seems that your idea is pre-baked at best. You will either need to first let it bake some more and post a more informative question. Or you can ask for a more pinpointed questions to improve/check your understanding of presheaves. For these reasons, I would (if somebody starts a close) to close. "Sheaves in geometry and logic" is excellent for learning about this.

Comment: @Ittay Yes.. the more I dig deep in to the theory, I see that my oven is not working correctly - hence I am going to continue to bake. I will reformulate the question soon.